# Reading WMI Classes from non-defaul namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, scope, wmi

i have a simple Problem. I cant read a specific Instance of an WMI class.

```
ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\OpenHardwareMonitor", null);
scope.Connect();
ManagementPath printersPath = new ManagementPath("Sensor");            
ObjectGetOptions options = new ObjectGetOptions(null, TimeSpan.MaxValue, true);

ManagementClass printersManager = new ManagementClass(scope, printersPath, options);
foreach (ManagementObject printer in printersManager.GetInstances())
{
    Console.WriteLine(printer["Name"]);
}

ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(scope.Path + ":Sensor.Name='CPU'");

ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject();
disk.Path = path;
disk.Get();
```

Here i get an exception, but the upper list works and 'CPU' is shown.

The Exeption points to the ';' of Get(). Details: (using German VS12)

```
System.Management.ManagementException wurde nicht behandelt.
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=Ungültiger Objektpfad <--- invalid objektpath
  Source=System.Management
  StackTrace:
       bei System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
       bei System.Management.ManagementObject.Get()
       bei Hello_openHWM.Program.getCPUTemp() in c:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Hello openHWM\Hello openHWM\Program.cs:Zeile 46.
       bei Hello_openHWM.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Hello openHWM\Hello openHWM\Program.cs:Zeile 18.
       bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

What am i doing wrong? I am new to C#

Comment: Can you show exception details?

Comment: And show exactly _where_ you get the exception.

Comment: sure. i edited it in starting post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems which you are passing the wrong [WMI object path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the WMI, as workaround you can use a `WQL` sentence to retrieve the proper data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;

namespace GetWMI_Info
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                ManagementScope Scope;                
                Scope = new ManagementScope(String.Format("\\\\{0}\\root\\OpenHardwareMonitor", "."), null);

                Scope.Connect();
                ObjectQuery Query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Sensor Where Name LIKE 'CPU%'");
                ManagementObjectSearcher Searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(Scope, Query);

                foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in Searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Identifier",WmiObject["Identifier"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Index",WmiObject["Index"]);// Sint32
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","InstanceId",WmiObject["InstanceId"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Max",WmiObject["Max"]);// Real32
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Min",WmiObject["Min"]);// Real32
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Name",WmiObject["Name"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Parent",WmiObject["Parent"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","ProcessId",WmiObject["ProcessId"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","SensorType",WmiObject["SensorType"]);// String
                    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}","Value",WmiObject["Value"]);// Real32

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Exception {0} Trace {1}",e.Message,e.StackTrace));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does the % after CPU mean wildcard? because there are instances with names like 'CPU #1'.

Comment: Yes it's a wildcard, you can modify the WQL sentence as you want.